# Is there a way to create the type of line graph described below in QuickBase?

Tags: visualization, quickbase

Currently, I have a QuickBase table that is designed like the picture here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZeph.png

I'd love to visualize the percent of people that answered "Y" for each date in a line graph. Is this possible in QuickBase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to build a weekly trend report. If so you could implement a Weeks table that would allow you to summarize the Total # of records from your data table that are associated to each week and also how many of those records have a value of Y. You could then created a numeric formula field on the Weeks table that calculates: [Total] / [Total answered Y] and plot that value on a line chart.

Here is a link to presentation that explains how you could create this type of table and setup Quick Base Automations for creating the records needs for your reports: https://university.quickbase.com/empower2019-course/342324